# Union three tables and show where data came from (extended)

Tags: sql, union

There are three tables each with a column of names, for example

- Table 1 - column name 'Name' - values 'A', 'B' and 'C'
- Table 2 - column name 'Name' - values 'A' and 'B'
- Table 3 - column nane 'Name' - values 'A' and 'C'

The goal is to UNION the tables - each value of the three tables should be shown only one time. In addition there should be three new "virtual columns" showing in which table the value is included('1' when value is included, '0' if not). So the result should look like this:

```
  Name| Table1 | Table2 | Table3
  A   |    1   |    1   |    1
  B   |    1   |    1   |    0
  C   |    1   |    0   |    1
```

Working solution for this is:

```
select Name, max(Table1) as Table1, max(Table2) as Table2, max(Table3) as Table3
from (select Name, 1 as Table1, 0 as Table2, 0 as Table3
      from table1
      union all
      select Name, 0 as Table1, 1 as Table2, 0 as Table3
      from table2
      union all
      select Name, 0 as Table1, 0 as Table2, 1 as Table3
      from table3
     ) t
group by Name;
```

Now there should be one more column let's say in table 1 called 'Company', for example

- Table 1 - column name 'Name' - values 'A', 'B' and 'C', column name 'Company' - values 'XYZ', '', 'ZYX'
- Table 2 - column name 'Name' - values 'A' and 'B'
- Table 3 - column nane 'Name' - values 'A' and 'C'

Desired result is:

```
Name | Table1 | Table2 | Table3 | Company
   A | 1 | 1 | 1 | XYZ
   B | 1 | 1 | 0 | ''
   C | 1 | 0 | 1 | ZYX
```

I don't succeed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to each subquery and then the outer query:

```
select Name, max(Table1) as Table1, max(Table2) as Table2, max(Table3) as Table3,
       max(Company) as Company
from (select Name, 1 as Table1, 0 as Table2, 0 as Table3, Company
      from table1
      union all
      select Name, 0 as Table1, 1 as Table2, 0 as Table3, NULL as Company
      from table2
      union all
      select Name, 0 as Table1, 0 as Table2, 1 as Table3, NULL as Company
      from table3
     ) t
group by Name;
```

Note:  this assumes that the company has only one value for each `Name`.

Comment: and a fast acceptance is nice too (hint: accept the answer)